# How to add the Javascript block correctly in .js file

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am adding this to .js file, I should remove Script tag from starting and end?
Is there anything else that I should add or remove, so that this works correctly?

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
   var wid = window.innerWidth;
  var hit = window.innerHeight;
  
  //alert( w );
  var geturl = window.location.href;
  var spliturl = geturl.split("layout=");
  
 if( geturl.indexOf("default") > -1 || spliturl[1] == 'default' ){
     var atr = "";
  var septer = "";
  
  $("a").each(function(index, element) {
   if( $(this).attr("id") != "desktop-view" && $(this).attr("id") != "mobile-view" ) {
    atr = $(this).attr("href");
    
    if( atr != undefined) {
     if( atr.toString().indexOf("?") > -1) {
      septer = "&";
     } else {
      septer = "?"; 
     }
     
     
     if( atr.indexOf("#") <= -1 && atr.indexOf("add_to_cart") <= -1) {
      $(this).attr("href", atr + septer + "layout=default");
     }
    }
   }
  });
  
  
  var murl = geturl;
  murl = murl.replace("&layout=default","");
  murl = murl.replace("layout=default","");
  $("#mobile-view").attr("href", murl);
  

  if(/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
   //alert( window.innerHeight + " |  " + window.innerWidth );
   if( wid == 375 ||  wid == 667 || (wid == 320 && hit >=400) || wid == 568 || wid == 414 || wid == 736 ) { //|| wid == 414 || wid == 736 added
    $("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content','initial-scale=0, minimum-scale=0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes');
    //alert("target device");
   } else {
    $("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content','width=100%, initial-scale=0');
   }
   /*} else {
    $("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=0'); 
   }*/
   
  } else {
   $("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=0'); 
  }
  
   
  
   
   if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $("#mobile-view").attr("style", "display:block !important");
    $("#desktop-view").attr("style", "display:none !important");
   }
    
  }else{
   if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $("#mobile-view").attr("style", "display:none !important");
    $("#desktop-view").attr("style", "display:block !important");
   }   
    
   var tt='<link href="/assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="res-css" />';
   $("head").append(tt);
   $("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
   
   
     $("a").each(function(index, element) {
   if( $(this).attr("id") == "desktop-view" ) {
    var vurl = geturl;
 
    if( vurl.indexOf("?") > -1 ) {
     vurl = vurl.replace("?","");
    }
    
    vurl = vurl.split('?');
    //parts = vurl[0].split("/");
    vurl = vurl[0] + "?layout=default";
    
    $(this).attr("href", vurl);
     
   }
  });
   
    
  }
  
    });
 
</script>
```

This code is included from .html file to another .html, I want to add this in .js file rather than including it from .html file.
If anything is unclear, ask question first.

Comment: You don't need the `<script>` tags in a `.js` file. Only in HTML.

Comment: For more organisational code you can create new js file and include it in your main js file, Take a look at **[Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to remove the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and

```
</script>
```

tags, if you want this code in a javascript file. Those script tags are HTML tags which are unnecessary if you have a dedicated javascript file. Of course you then need to ensure you link to the file itself in your HTML, with a line like this:

```
<script src="/yourownpathhere/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have added as you said but there seems to be a problem, if you inspect element this home page http://www.americaint.com/ ,I have control of this site. Under the Sources tab assets>js>common.js line 167, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" ? Shall I remove the "$" then it will work?

Comment: When you view page source, your common.js javascript file is loading before jQuery. So it doesn't know what $ is. You need to load jQuery first, before common.js.